# More complex sum of time in PHP or Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

I would like to sum just the times that does not repeat in a day, see the picture in the link below to understand better

http://postimage.org/image/ew50dnlw/

The total time should be **5 hours**

I don't want to count twice the yellow area because another time already filled that time

thanks!!

Comment: paste the piece of code here if you want people to help you

Comment: What do you have [tried] already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar to that, but using Telerik's RadScheduler, so I can't provide you code but describe the logic.

I'll assume you already have those appointments in an array, ordered by start date

First run:

1. Get the first appointment
2. Read start time
3. Read end time
4. Sum difference to a variable

Subsequent runs:

1. Get the next appointment
2. Read start time
3. Read end time
4. Compare this start date with
   previous end date
5. If it's smaller (they interpolate),
   sum difference between this end time
   with previous end time
6. Else (they don't interpolate), sum difference between this
   end time with this start time

Please provide your code, so I can help you better

Comment: But if I have a subsequent run that has two times inside its start and end ? maybe helps if I order by start time ASC before compare them, what do you think ?

Comment: You're right, you'll have to compare end time too. About ordering by start time, I've stated that in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that.
I'll try something here using your idea
just a minute

Comment: Ok, if you find any problem, please come back with a code we can work on

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea proposed by Andre in above answer I could achieve the goal with the code below:
Note: To get this working properly don't forget to order your times by start time ASC

```
<?php
// Function to sum times
function sum($time1, $time2) {
    $times = array($time1, $time2);
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);
        $seconds += $hour * 3600;
        $seconds += $minute * 60;
        $seconds += $second;
    }
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
// Function to subtract times
function sub($end, $start) {
    $end = strtotime($end);
    $start = strtotime($start);

    $seconds = $end - $start;

    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;

    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
// Some values to work on
// To get this working the times should be ordered by start time ASC
$start = array(
    '11:00:00',
    '13:00:00',
    '14:00:00',
    '15:00:00',
);

$end = array(
    '12:30:00',
    '14:30:00',
    '16:00:00',
    '16:30:00',
);

$total = "00:00:00";
$tmp = "00:00:00";

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($start); $i++) {

    $start_t = $start[$i];
    $end_t = $end[$i];

    if ($start_t >= $tmp) {
        $total = sum(sub($end_t, $start_t), $total);
        $tmp = $end_t;
    } else {
        if ($end_t > $tmp) {
            $total = sum(sub($end_t, $tmp), $total);
            $tmp = $end_t;
        } else {

        }
    }
}
echo $total;
```